# Software to wipe my screen (display black color and ignore tactile input)

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, display, touchscreen

Tactile screens tend to gather fingerprints at a very high pace, so I clean mine with a wet tissue every few days.

PROBLEM:

- If I clean my screen when it is locked, the background is not dark enough so I can't clean perfectly.
- If I clean on a black terminal, the tissue clicks the tactile screen everywhere, which is dangerous.
- Switching off could be an idea, but closing all apps (VMs, terminal, etc) + rebooting + relaunching the apps takes incredible time and is very inconvenient, I must avoid that.

So I need a program that:

- Makes the entire screen black
- Does not react on clicks
- Free and open source
- Works on latest Ubuntu